# JSON.parse() isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I don't understand why my `json.parse()` isn't working. The error is probably right before my eyes but I can't find it. Here is the code that I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Stage galerij</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="img/website/photo.jpg" type="image/jpg" sizes="any">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="id01"></div>
  <script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://www.clouddesk.be/galerij/includes/galerij_array.php";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function myFunction(response) {
      var arr = JSON.parse(response);
      var i;
      var out = "<table>";

      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" +
          arr[i].id +
          "</td><td>" +
          arr[i].File_path +
          "</td><td>" +
          arr[i].uitleg +
          "</td></tr>";
      }
      out += "</table>";
      document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the code of the php file:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "clouddesk_robbe", "password", "clouddesk_stage");

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Fotos");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"id":"'  . $rs["idFotos"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"File_path":"'   . $rs["Foto_File"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"uitleg":"'  . $rs["Uitleg"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"alt":"'. $rs["Alternatief"]     . '"}'; 
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

It outputs this json string:

```
[{"id":"2","File_path":"img\gallerij\Afbeelding-61.png","uitleg":"Zebra verliest zijn strepen.","alt":"Stressige zebra"},{"id":"3","File_path":"img\gallerij\download(1).jpg","uitleg":"Tomatensoep met balletjes: Nog een keer blazen en ik sla op je bek.","alt":"Grappige cartoon"},{"id":"4","File_path":"img\gallerij\download.jpg","uitleg":"Brilsmurf met een raar gezicht","alt":"Brilsmurf"},{"id":"5","File_path":"img\gallerij\download(2).jpg","uitleg":"Mooi avondlijk woestijnuitzicht.","alt":"Woestijnuitzicht"},{"id":"8","File_path":"img\gallerij\image1.jpg","uitleg":"Een mooi blaadje dat door het herfstseizoen van de boom is gevallen en eenzaam op de grond licht. Het is getrokken in de late herfstzon.","alt":"Herfstblaadje op de grond"},{"id":"9","File_path":"img\gallerij\7.jpg","uitleg":"Een kleurrijk paneel dat elke mens wel terug wat opfleurd.","alt":"Een kleurig paneel"},{"id":"10","File_path":"img\gallerij\images(1).jpg","uitleg":"Mooie foto van een golf die in de late avond getrokken is. Je ziet de reflectie van de zo in de buiging van de golf.","alt":"Golf in de avondzon"},{"id":"12","File_path":"img\gallerij\images.jpg","uitleg":"Mooie auto, het is een dure rode lexus getrokken langs de linker voorkant.","alt":"Mooie rode lexus"},{"id":"13","File_path":"img\gallerij\Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg","uitleg":"Een uitzicht op een onbewoond eiland zoals je je voorstelt in je verbeelding","alt":"Een onbewoond eiland"},{"id":"14","File_path":"img\gallerij\image-slider-2.jpg","uitleg":"Het huis van de film up in de lucht doormiddel van duizenden ballonen aan de schoorsteen.","alt":"Huis in de lucht"},{"id":"15","File_path":"img\gallerij\demo-image.jpg","uitleg":"Een mooie foto van een zwaan.","alt":"foto van een zwaan"}]
```

I copied practically everything from this page of w3schools.com:
http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_example.asp
When I tested it with the original code of w3schools.com it worked perfectly. But when I changed the URL variable and the array names, it doesn't work anymore. I also tested if the json ouput was valid with an online validator and it said it was completely fine.

Comment: Stop building your JSON strings manually for one. Use `json_encode`. Besides that "it isn't working" is not a sufficient problem description.

Comment: you know you could just put your rows in an array and echo json_encode(array), right?

Comment: jsonlint throws an error in the JSON that you provided (something about `undefined`, cannot locate it). Look at the browser's console log, maybe it shows a better debug message.

Comment: Just try without `JSON.parse();` like `var arr = response;`, as `JSON.parse` throws error when object is already JSON

Comment: if you use jQuery anyway, then why don't you use $.getJSON instead of the plain javascript ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.parse() is not working because json string is not proper. `File_path` is
`img\gallerij\Afbeelding-61.png` but it should be `img/gallerij/demo-image.jpg`. Please change `File_path` everywhere in json string .

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1hsq7rm1/1/) for jsfiddle example.

`File_path` is getting generated from  `$outp .= '"File_path":"'. $rs["Foto_File"]        . '",';` So replace `\` with `/`.

Benefit: You get a path using `JSON.parse()` like `img/gallerij/demo-image.jpg` directly in client, so that this path can be used directly as `src` of DOM element.

Comment: so i tested this and this works indeed but know i get a very long string as result, how can I get an array? But thanks anyway

Comment: I did that but doesn't really makes a difference now I get [object Object] when I display the array, what does that mean?

Comment: Updated jsfiddle sample, "click here for jsfiddle example" - click in that link.

Comment: Thanks everyone I have it. This was my first question on stackoverflow, it is very practical and I think I will use this a lot more often in the future.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please accept the answer by selecting the check mark (attached to the answer).

Comment: Yes, but there is the problem I used multiple answers to get it working wich should I select then?

Comment: You select the best answer according to you :-) If not, vote for the answers, it can be one or can be multiple.

Answer (score 2):

Do not create your JSON output yourself, use json_encode instead of string concatenation. A simple sample is below;

```
<?PHP
    $myResult = array();
    $myResult["key"] = "Value";
    $myResult["innerArray"] = array();
    $myResult["innerArray"]["key"] = "Value";
    $myResult["innerArray"]["isOk"] = true;
    $myResult["innerArray"]["amount"] = 100;
    echo json_encode($myResult);
?>
```

Working example of my sample https://ideone.com/4Kvvpj

Answer (score 0):

use JSON_encode();
 for encoding your json value in php file