# "Syntax Error: missing } after property list" How to make Javascript symbol proof?

Tags: javascript, php

I have this JS snippet which displays icons on the map with description. Occasionaly map does not display and I have

"Syntax Error: missing } after property list"

while debuging in Firefox. 
I couldn't find the mistake in the code so I figured out this might be due to special signs in variable names like: "," "()", etc. Is there a way to make this code symbol-proof?

```js
// <![CDATA[
 jQuery(document).ready(
   function() {
     jQuery("#mapobjects").GoogleMaps({
       "dataSource": "Recordset",
       "dataSourceType": "dynamic",
       "zoom": "fit",
       "markers": [ <? php
         do { ?> {
             "latitude": <? php echo $row_Recordsetmapa['object_lat']; ?> , 
             "longitude": <? php echo $row_Recordsetmapa['object_lng']; ?> , 
             "html": "<a href='Obiekt.php?OID=<?php echo $row_Recordsetmapa['ID_object']; ?>'><?php echo        $row_Recordsetmapa['object_name']; ?>",
             "title": "<?php echo $row_Recordsetmapa['object_name']; ?>",
             "icon": {
             "image": "images//m<?php echo $_GET['Cat']; ?>.png",
             "iconsize": [70, 70],
             "iconanchor": [13, 26],
             }
           }, <? php
         } while ($row_Recordsetmapa = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetmapa)); ?>
       ]
     });
   }
 );
 // ]]>
```

Comment: You should not build json manually in php; generate an array / object structure as you need it and use `json_encode` to generate valid json that you can output to javascript.

Comment: Also your code is vulnerable to xss attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create markers Javascript array with json_encode creating such this data manually is not a good way. Check my answer on this link [JSON.parse() isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080089/json-parse-isnt-working/35080245#35080245)

also a dummy example of your question is below;

```
<?PHP
    $markerObject = new stdClass();
    $markerObject->latitude = "41.015137";
    $markerObject->longitude = "28.979530";
    $markerObject->html = "<a href=\"href...\">Bla bla...</a>";
    $markerObject->title = "Marker title";
    $markerObject->icon = new stdClass();
    $markerObject->icon->image = "path_of_image.png";
    $markerObject->icon->iconsize = array();
    $markerObject->icon->iconsize[] = 70;
    $markerObject->icon->iconsize[] = 70;
    $markerObject->icon->iconanchor = array();
    $markerObject->icon->iconanchor[] = 13;
    $markerObject->icon->iconanchor[] = 26;

    $markers = array();
    for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++)
    {
        $markers[] = $markerObject;
    }

    $markersJson = json_encode($markers);

?>
```

working example of the PHP code above is here https://ideone.com/APxfm9 and your javascript code should be like below;

```
// <![CDATA[
 jQuery(document).ready(
   function() {
     jQuery("#mapobjects").GoogleMaps({
       "dataSource": "Recordset",
       "dataSourceType": "dynamic",
       "zoom": "fit",
       "markers": <?PHP echo $markersJson; ?>
     });
   }
 );
 // ]]>
```

Comment: Thank you Cihan! Your answer is very detailed and perfect for a beginner like me :) 
But I am also having the problem with result output. Right now the 1st row repeated multiple times. Would you mind helping me turning result into proper array?

Comment: @Piotrek you should create $markerObject inside your while loop and for each time you should add your $markerObject to array like that - while ($row_Recordsetmapa = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetmapa)){ $markers[] = $markerObject;  } at the end of while loop you will get your  array clearly.